# Building a 4x16 decoder with only four 2x4 enabled decoder

Tags: integrated-circuit, decoder

I am trying to build a 4x16 decoder with only 4 decoder.. I've just made this. Basically each decoder has 2 enable signals. Is it correct? 
[image]

Comment: This is nonsense. You need additional AND and NOR/OR gates to decode the 4 address lines properly. The circuit you are showing would have each group of 4 outputs duplicate the same pattern. Or just buy a 74HC154 1 of 16 decoder.

Comment: what is the part number of the decoders that you are using?

Comment: Why this is nonsense? For example: for CD = 11 only one output of the last decoder will be 1.. the other decoders will give zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct as shown.  However, I don't think there is a real world decode or demux part that has two pairs of complimentary enable pins with all of the internal logic to make them work. To build your schematic you will have to add some inverters to some of the device select/enable inputs.